# Extract the real parameter type of a given function

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to extract the real parameter type (i.e. the `subtype` of an interface) from a given function.
My problem is the following: For a common interface `I` and classes `A` and `B`:

```
export interface I {...}
export class A implements I {...}
export class B implements I {...}
```

and an `asnychron` function `doStuff` that sends a value to my Backend and gets as result some response of either type A or B (or some implementation of I)

```
 export type CallbackFunction = (response: I) => void;
 export function doStuff(value, functions: CallbackFunction[]) {...}
```

I want to give my function `doStuff` as parameters callback functions like this:

```
doStuff(value, [
    (response: A) => {...},
    (response: B) => {...}  
  ]
);
```

Now should be able to differentiate between the given functions and call the correct one deciding on the actual subclass of the given response.

To this point, I only know that the parameter functions is an array of CallbackFunction. Is there a way to have more information about this? Or even do something like

```
 for (let f of functions) {
   if (f instanceof (model: typeOf response) => void) {...}
 }
```

Best regards

Comment: Since the response from the backend will be either `class A` or `class B` at runtime there is no way to directly infer it with TypeScript. Instead, use JavaScript logic to manually test for some feature of the class that will differentiate it. For example if only `class A` has the property `X`, test that `X` exists on the response data and then you will know what class you are dealing with and call the function accordingly.

Comment: Can't I get the type of the response at runtime with `typeOf` or `instanceof`? Nonetheless, we actually already have this encoded in our classes `class A`, `class B`,...  
My question is more about matching the type of the response with the given functions, meaning can I get the actual type of a function parameter in the given functions array.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Do you want to know the type of the argument from inside the function body, or from outside of it? You can use the utility type `Parameters<MyFunctionType>` to extract them externally.